# How to show trailing spaces on line with background color?

Tags: vim, vi

How can I in VIM show the trailing spaces/tab before the line end with a different background color? Is this possible?

So something like this:

[image: Trailing lines in background color]

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure about the background, but to make trailing spaces visible, you can use

```
set list listchars=trail:x
```

where `x` is the character shown in place of each one of the trailing spaces.

This means that if you use a "full block" character (see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_Elements)), you obtain pretty much the result you want.
[image]
Except that I have no idea how to control its color.

Answer (score 1):

[image: trailing spaces]

Here is a quick and dirty solution:

```
augroup TrailingSpaces
    autocmd!
    autocmd winEnter,BufEnter * call clearmatches() | call matchadd('ColorColumn', '\s\+$', 100)
augroup END
```

Comments:

- The autocommand is triggered on `:help winEnter` and `:help bufEnter`. This is not optimal but necessary to handle some corner cases.
- `:help matchadd()` allows us to add any number of matches in the current window.
- `:help clearmatches()` will clear everything that was added with `matchadd()`, including stuff from plugins. Once again, this is not an optimal approach and you may encounter side-effects.

Comment: Why from the 80th columns onward?

Comment: Bad copypasta from a gist of mine, which is for a similar problem.